# Android NDK ARM build settings to run on most devices?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, neon

I've got a few Android NDK apps out and people complain my app doesn't work on their phones.  What I'd like to know is what are the compilation settings that will support most if not all ARM devices on the market?

My problem seems to be armeabi-v7a devices that have a varying amount of support for VFP, NEON, etc.  I'm looking for a solution to build apps that run on the most platforms, even if that's at the cost of optimization.

I was using the default NDK build scripts for armeabi and armeabi-v7a, that specified:
`-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3`

This does not work on some devices, for example on Acer A500 (CPU Nvidia Tegra2 (Dual Cortex A9)).  This CPU does not implement NEON, from what I'm learning here http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison.

The crash, specifically, is this:

```
F/libc    (15549): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x5bfd9260 (code=1)
...(snip)...
I/DEBUG   (   81): #00 pc 0005b260 /data/data/com.burnsmod.oscpad/lib/libapplication.so (tanf)
```

Looking at libapplication.so, I see tanf is being generated as:

```
0005b25c <tanf>:
5b25c:       ee070a90        fmsr    s15, r0
5b260:       eef70ae7        fcvtds  d16, s15
5b264:       e92d4010        push    {r4, lr}
5b268:       ec510b30        vmov    r0, r1, d16
5b26c:       ebff4b6c        bl      2e024 <_ZN15ButtonUIHandler10FreeImagesEv-0x6ac>
5b270:       ec410b30        vmov    d16, r0, r1
5b274:       eef77be0        fcvtsd  s15, d16
5b278:       ee170a90        fmrs    r0, s15
5b27c:       e8bd8010        pop     {r4, pc}
```

So, what's the answer?  vfpv2?  vfp?  vfpv3?  vfpv3-d16?

Right now if I use readelf I find my application library's dependencies are:

```
MacBook:armeabi-v7a tom$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -A libapplication.so
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
Tag_CPU_arch: v7
Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
Tag_VFP_arch: VFPv3
Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
Tag_ABI_align8_needed: Yes
Tag_ABI_align8_preserved: Yes, except leaf SP
Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
```

**VFP2**: Compiling with '-mfpu=vfpv2' or '-mfpu=vfp2' isn't supported in NDK 7, both return an error message.

Comment: Normally, when the compatibility is more important than optimization, you aim for the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @Seva Definitely.  So what is it?  VFP is mentioned as being 'obsolete', so is it VFPv2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out my problem was that I was using NDK r7b, which had bugs where VFPv3 code was included in some core libraries.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26199

It was fixed in r7c and by upgrading to r8b it looks like I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By building both a vanilla and an armv7-optimized library (armeabi and armeabi-v7a) you cover the situations of armv7 and non-armv7, as the package manager will select the appropriate library when the user installs your app.

Within the armv7-optimized library you could use [android_getCpuFeatures()](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html) to detect support for VFPv3-D16 and NEON, and select the appropriate code path based on that. I.e., you can execute any VFPv3-D16-optimized code that you have if `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_VFPv3` is set, and any NEON/VFPv3-D32-optimized code if `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON` is set (assuming that no devices lie about what they support).

Comment: Thanks for the info - but I'm not writing the VFPv3 / NEON dependent code.  It's being chosen for me during compilation (ie tanf is being generated dependent on vfpv3)

Comment: In that case your best bet is probably to compile the armeabi-v7a library with `-mfpu=vfpv3`, if you really want to support Tegra 2-based devices and don't want to have a Tegra 2-specific version of your app.

Comment: Actually Tegra2 only supports vfpv3-d16.  I've sent a copy of my app built with that to the people who were complaining of crashes, hopefully it solves the issue and I can go back to productive coding.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, vfpv3-d16 is what I meant (copy-paste error). Another possibility could be to build multiple armeabi-v7a versions of your library - e.g. one with neon optimizations and one with vfpv3-d16 optimizations - and decide which one to load at runtime based on what getCpuFeatures returns (I haven't tried this approach myself so I can't say anything about how practical it would be).